# How to add image on the table using RTF gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rtf

I'm generating rtf document using rtf gem and i was asked to add image on the table(not in a cell). How can I do that?

```
   doc.table(1, 2, 7600, 1400) do |tr|
     tr[0][0].top_border_width = 4
     tr[1][0].bottom_border_width = 4
     tr[0][1] << 'Image here'
     tr[1][1] << 'should cover this'
   end
```

Comment: what do you mean "on the table(not in a cell)" ? It appears from source you cannot merge cells and it does not allow for table nesting so I am not sure how you intend to accomplish this with the `rtf` gem.

Comment: So it's not possible to do something like set coordinates for picture?